# Scraping a custom ebay search with BeautifulSoup. How to handle pagination?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, ebay-api

I am trying to scrape a custom eBay search that shows 200 items on a single page. I need to get the title of the item, the price and the link to the said item. So far so good. But I also would like the code to follow the link to the next page with 200 or less items and extract them as well.

This is the code, I am using:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as Req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as souce

start_url='https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_fosrp=1&_from=R40&_nkw=iphone&_in_kw=1&_ex_kw=&_sacat=0&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=600&_udhi=4.800&LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=4&_ftrt=901&_ftrv=1&_sabdlo=&_sabdhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=10&_fpos=&LH_SubLocation=1&_sargn=-1%26saslc%3D0&_fsradio2=%26LH_LocatedIn%3D1&_salic=77&_saact=77&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_sop=2&_dmd=1&_ipg=200'


Client=Req(start_url)
page_html=Client.read()
Client.close()


page_soup=souce(page_html, "html.parser")


containers_listings = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"sresult lvresult clearfix li"})
container_next=page_soup.find("td",{"class":"pagn-next"})
next_url=container_next.a["href"]

filename="scrape_ebay.csv"
f=open(filename,"w")
headers="item_title,item_link,item_price\n"
f.write(headers)

for container in containers_listings:
item_title=container.h3.text.strip()
item_link=container.h3.a["href"].strip()
item_price=container.span.text.strip()

f.write(item_title + "," + item_link + "," + item_price.replace(",",".") + "\n")

f.close()
```

I am running into a problem with the eBay pagination. I have managed to isolate and extract the next link but I have no idea how to implement it into a loop that would visit the next pages and extract the information. Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your current link garners results under 200, thus, no pagination is given, however, navigating to a more popular page, such as listings for "macbooks" yields results on multiple pages. The link used for demonstration can be found [here](https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_sop=2&_nkw=macbook&_frs=1&_pgn=1). To find the pages, the full pagination `a` tag text can be found, and when looping over the latter results, the page number at the current iteration can be concatenated at the end of the link:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests, re
from collections import namedtuple
def check_under_val(val = 200):
  def outer(f):
    def wrapper(cls):
      if cls.page is not None:
        raise StopIteration("Search results for given link under {}".format(val))
      return f(cls)
    return wrapper
  return outer

class Results:
   product = namedtuple('product', ['title', 'description', 'price', 'rating', 'link'])
   def __init__(self, link):
      self.link = link
      self.pagination = [i.text for i in soup(requests.get(link).text, 'html.parser').find_all('li', {'class':'x-pagination__li'})] 
      self.page = [Results.product(*i) for i in Results.scrape_page(self.link)] if not self.pagination else None 
   @staticmethod
   def concatenate(link, num:str):
      return re.sub('\d+$', num, link)
   @staticmethod
   def scrape_page(url):
     current_page = soup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
     tags = [['h3', 's-item__title'], ['span', 'SECONDARY_INFO'], ['span', 's-item__price'], ['span', 'b-starrating__star'], ['a', 's-item__link']]
     items = [i for i in current_page.find_all('li', {'class':'s-item'})]
     return [[getattr(i.find(tag, {'class':c}), 'text', 'N/A') for tag, c in tags] for i in items]
   @check_under_val(val = 200)
   def __iter__(self):
     for page in self.pagination:
       yield [Results.product(*i) for i in Results.scrape_page(Results.concatenate(self.link, page))]

start = 'https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_sop=2&_nkw=macbook&_frs=1&_pgn=1'
r = Results(start)
for page_results in r:
  print(page_results)
```

Output (first printed result):

```
[product(title='SSD 1TB 1Terabyte passend für Apple Macbook Pro und Air Modelle', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='N/A', link='SSD 1TB 1Terabyte passend für Apple Macbook Pro und Air Modelle'), product(title='Apple MacBook Pro A1398 39,1 cm (15,4 Zoll) Nur Display', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Pro A1398 39,1 cm (15,4 Zoll) Nur Display', link='Apple MacBook Pro A1398 39,1 cm (15,4 Zoll) Nur Display'), product(title='Neues AngebotMacbook Late 2008', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotMacbook Late 2008'), product(title='Apple MacBook Pro 39,1 cm (15,4 Zoll) Laptop - MB134D/A (Februar, 2008)', description='Nur Ersatzteile', price='EUR 1,00', rating='3.5 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Pro 39,1 cm (15,4 Zoll) Laptop - MB134D/A (Februar, 2008)', link='Apple MacBook Pro 39,1 cm (15,4 Zoll) Laptop - MB134D/A (Februar, 2008)'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro 2,53 Ghz (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Juni, 2009), viel Leistung!', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='4.5 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Pro 2,53 Ghz (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Juni, 2009), viel Leistung!', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro 2,53 Ghz (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Juni, 2009), viel Leistung!'), product(title='Neues AngebotMacBook Pro 15.4" Matt - Gebraucht, Mitte 2009', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotMacBook Pro 15.4" Matt - Gebraucht, Mitte 2009'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple Macbook Air 11 inch late 2010 128 gb', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotApple Macbook Air 11 inch late 2010 128 gb'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook A1342 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Mai, 2010) - Individuelle Konfig', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='4.5 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook A1342 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Mai, 2010) - Individuelle Konfig', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook A1342 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Mai, 2010) - Individuelle Konfig'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Air A1370 29,5 cm (11,6 Zoll) Laptop - MC506D/A (Oktober, 2010)', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Air A1370 29,5 cm (11,6 Zoll) Laptop - MC506D/A (Oktober, 2010)', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Air A1370 29,5 cm (11,6 Zoll) Laptop - MC506D/A (Oktober, 2010)'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook A1342 13,3 Zoll mid 2010, 2,4GHz, 320GB HDD', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='4.5 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook A1342 13,3 Zoll mid 2010, 2,4GHz, 320GB HDD', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook A1342 13,3 Zoll mid 2010, 2,4GHz, 320GB HDD'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro 15" Mitte 2009 2,66 Ghz 8GB RAM 64 BIT 500GB HDD Laptop Matt', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro 15" Mitte 2009 2,66 Ghz 8GB RAM 64 BIT 500GB HDD Laptop Matt'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Air - 8 GB! - 13,3 Zoll Laptop, MJVE2D/A, kaum benutzt / quasi neu', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Air - 8 GB! - 13,3 Zoll Laptop, MJVE2D/A, kaum benutzt / quasi neu'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro A1278 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Juni, 2009)', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro A1278 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Juni, 2009)'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple Macbook Pro Modell (15 Zoll) Top Zustand  DVD Brenner, MacOS X', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,00', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotApple Macbook Pro Modell (15 Zoll) Top Zustand  DVD Brenner, MacOS X'), product(title='Apple Macbook Pro 13 Zoll silber   ', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,50', rating='N/A', link='Apple Macbook Pro 13 Zoll silber   '), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Air A1369 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MC965D/A (Juli, 2011)', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 1,50', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Air A1369 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MC965D/A (Juli, 2011)', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Air A1369 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MC965D/A (Juli, 2011)'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro A1278 13,3 Zoll Laptop Anfang 2011 i5 2,3Ghz 8GB DDR3 in OVP !', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 2,00', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Pro A1278 13,3 Zoll Laptop Anfang 2011 i5 2,3Ghz 8GB DDR3 in OVP !', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro A1278 13,3 Zoll Laptop Anfang 2011 i5 2,3Ghz 8GB DDR3 in OVP !'), product(title='Apple MacBook Pro (13,3 Zoll, 2009) - 120GB SSD - 2GB RAM', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 2,50', rating='N/A', link='Apple MacBook Pro (13,3 Zoll, 2009) - 120GB SSD - 2GB RAM'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook 12“ Space Grau/ 1.1 GHz/ 8GB/ 256 GB inkl. Zubehör', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 2,72', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook 12“ Space Grau/ 1.1 GHz/ 8GB/ 256 GB inkl. Zubehör'), product(title='Apple MacBook Pro A1286 39,1 cm, 2011, 16gb, SSD + HDD, HI-RES', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 4,00', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Pro A1286 39,1 cm, 2011, 16gb, SSD + HDD, HI-RES', link='Apple MacBook Pro A1286 39,1 cm, 2011, 16gb, SSD + HDD, HI-RES'), product(title='Original Karton - Apple MacBook Air (2014) - Intel i5 1,4 GHz, 4GB - NUR KARTON', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 4,95', rating='N/A', link='Original Karton - Apple MacBook Air (2014) - Intel i5 1,4 GHz, 4GB - NUR KARTON'), product(title='Macbook Air 13 Zoll Baujahr 2012 OHNE Festplatte Silber Space', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 5,00', rating='N/A', link='Macbook Air 13 Zoll Baujahr 2012 OHNE Festplatte Silber Space'), product(title='Apple MacBook Pro A1286 39,1 cm (15,4 Zoll) Laptop -  (Juni, 2009)', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 6,00', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Pro A1286 39,1 cm (15,4 Zoll) Laptop -  (Juni, 2009)', link='Apple MacBook Pro A1286 39,1 cm (15,4 Zoll) Laptop -  (Juni, 2009)'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook 12" Laptop , 256GB - MNYF2D/A - August 2017, Space Grau neuwertig!', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 6,50', rating='1.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook 12" Laptop , 256GB - MNYF2D/A - August 2017, Space Grau neuwertig!', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook 12" Laptop , 256GB - MNYF2D/A - August 2017, Space Grau neuwertig!'), product(title='MacBook Pro 15 Zoll A1211 Defekt', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 8,00', rating='N/A', link='MacBook Pro 15 Zoll A1211 Defekt'), product(title='Apple Macbook Pro 13', description='Brandneu', price='EUR 8,26', rating='N/A', link='Apple Macbook Pro 13'), product(title='Apple MacBook A1342 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MC207D/A (Oktober, 2009)', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 8,50', rating='4.5 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook A1342 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MC207D/A (Oktober, 2009)', link='Apple MacBook A1342 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MC207D/A (Oktober, 2009)'), product(title='Apple Macbook Pro 13', description='Brandneu', price='EUR 8,63', rating='N/A', link='Apple Macbook Pro 13'), product(title='Apple MacBook 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop -(2008)', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 10,00', rating='4.5 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop -(2008)', link='Apple MacBook 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop -(2008)'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro A1502 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - ME865D/A (Oktober, 2013)', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 10,00', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Pro A1502 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - ME865D/A (Oktober, 2013)', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro A1502 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - ME865D/A (Oktober, 2013)'), product(title='Apple MacBook A1181 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MB061D/A ', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 10,50', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook A1181 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MB061D/A ', link='Apple MacBook A1181 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MB061D/A '), product(title="Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro  13.3'' A1706 256GB Laptop mit Touchbar - DEFEKT", description='Nur Ersatzteile', price='EUR 10,50', rating="5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Pro  13.3'' A1706 256GB Laptop mit Touchbar - DEFEKT", link="Neues AngebotApple MacBook Pro  13.3'' A1706 256GB Laptop mit Touchbar - DEFEKT"), product(title='apple macbook pro 13', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 10,50', rating='N/A', link='apple macbook pro 13'), product(title='Neues AngebotMacbook Pro 15 Zoll von 2007 A1211, 2 GB ram, Core 2 Duo, ATI Grafikkarte, 350GB', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 11,50', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotMacbook Pro 15 Zoll von 2007 A1211, 2 GB ram, Core 2 Duo, ATI Grafikkarte, 350GB'), product(title='Apple MacBook A1181 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop\xa0', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 11,50', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook A1181 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop\xa0', link='Apple MacBook A1181 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop\xa0'), product(title='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Air Mitte 2011 13,3 Zoll i5 121 GB SSD 4 GB RAM', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 11,50', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotApple MacBook Air Mitte 2011 13,3 Zoll i5 121 GB SSD 4 GB RAM'), product(title='Apple MacBook Pro 43,2 cm (17 Zoll) Laptop - MA611D/A (Oktober, 2006)', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 11,50', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Pro 43,2 cm (17 Zoll) Laptop - MA611D/A (Oktober, 2006)', link='Apple MacBook Pro 43,2 cm (17 Zoll) Laptop - MA611D/A (Oktober, 2006)'), product(title='Apple MacBook Pro 15“ 2,33 GHz 500GB HDD 2GB RAM', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 12,50', rating='N/A', link='Apple MacBook Pro 15“ 2,33 GHz 500GB HDD 2GB RAM'), product(title='Apple MacBook A1181 13,3 Zoll, 2,2 GHz 256GB HDD, 4GB Ram, OS X Lion & Bootcamp', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 12,50', rating='N/A', link='Apple MacBook A1181 13,3 Zoll, 2,2 GHz 256GB HDD, 4GB Ram, OS X Lion & Bootcamp'), product(title='MacBook 13‘‘ Ende 2009', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 13,50', rating='N/A', link='MacBook 13‘‘ Ende 2009'), product(title='Apple MacBook Pro 17 Zoll Core 2 Duo 2.33 GHz 3Gb Ram 100GB 7200rpm HDD', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 15,50', rating='N/A', link='Apple MacBook Pro 17 Zoll Core 2 Duo 2.33 GHz 3Gb Ram 100GB 7200rpm HDD'), product(title='Macbook pro A1278 Originalverpackung TOP', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 19,00', rating='N/A', link='Macbook pro A1278 Originalverpackung TOP'), product(title='Macbook Pro 13" 2017', description='Brandneu', price='EUR 21,41', rating='N/A', link='Macbook Pro 13" 2017'), product(title='2 x Original Apple Macbook Pro Retina 15“ Verpackung OVP Karton Box A1398', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 22,00', rating='N/A', link='2 x Original Apple Macbook Pro Retina 15“ Verpackung OVP Karton Box A1398'), product(title='Apple MacBook Air A1466 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MD760B/A (Juni, 2013)', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 22,50', rating='5.0 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Air A1466 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MD760B/A (Juni, 2013)', link='Apple MacBook Air A1466 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop - MD760B/A (Juni, 2013)'), product(title='MacBook Air 13, 2013', description='Brandneu', price='EUR 23,50', rating='N/A', link='MacBook Air 13, 2013'), product(title='Apple MacBook Pro A1278 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Juni, 2009) -...', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 25,00', rating='4.5 von 5 Sternen - Apple MacBook Pro A1278 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Juni, 2009) -...', link='Apple MacBook Pro A1278 33,8 cm (13,3 Zoll) Laptop (Juni, 2009) -...'), product(title='macbook pro 13', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 25,00', rating='N/A', link='macbook pro 13'), product(title='Neues AngebotMacBook Pro 15 Zoll Late 2011 Batterie', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 25,00', rating='N/A', link='Neues AngebotMacBook Pro 15 Zoll Late 2011 Batterie'), product(title='MacBook Air SuperDrive', description='Gebraucht', price='EUR 29,99', rating='N/A', link='MacBook Air SuperDrive')]
```

However, if the input does not contain pagination links, only the first page will be accessible:

```
start = 'https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_fosrp=1&_from=R40&_nkw=iphone&_in_kw=1&_ex_kw=&_sacat=0&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=600&_udhi=4.800&LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=4&_ftrt=901&_ftrv=1&_sabdlo=&_sabdhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=10&_fpos=&LH_SubLocation=1&_sargn=-1%26saslc%3D0&_fsradio2=%26LH_LocatedIn%3D1&_salic=77&_saact=77&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_sop=2&_dmd=1&_ipg=200'
r1 = Results(start)
for page in r1:
  print(page)
```

> StopIteration: Search results for given link under 200

**Update November 2019**:

The solution is outdated. A possible way to handle Ebay pagination currently is below:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def get_products(_d):
   return [{'link':i.h3.a['href'], 'title':i.h3.a.text, 'price':i.find('li', {'class':'lvprice prc'}).get_text(strip=True)} for i in _d.find('ul', {'id':'ListViewInner'}).find_all('li', {'id':re.compile('^item')})]

d = soup(requests.get('https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_fosrp=1&_from=R40&_nkw=iphone&_in_kw=1&_ex_kw=&_sacat=0&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=600&_udhi=4.800&LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=4&_ftrt=901&_ftrv=1&_sabdlo=&_sabdhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=10&_fpos=&LH_SubLocation=1&_sargn=-1%26saslc%3D0&_fsradio2=%26LH_LocatedIn%3D1&_salic=77&_saact=77&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_sop=2&_dmd=1&_ipg=200').text, 'html.parser')
vals = [get_products(d)]
while (k:=d.find('td', {'class':'pagn-next'}).a).attrs.get('aria-disabled') != 'true':
   d = soup(requests.get(k['href']).text, 'html.parser')
   vals.append(get_products(d))
```

Answer (score 1):

eBay has a [`_pgn`](https://serpapi.com/ebay-search-api#api-parameters-pagination--pgn)  [URL parameter](https://www.semrush.com/blog/url-parameters/) which responsible for pagination. With that in mind, we can increment its value by 1 for the second, third, and so on pages accordingly.

We need to increment the page value only when a certain condition is met and only use the `while` loop to paginate through all possible pages dynamically i.e not using `for i in range(1, 100)` which is hardcoded way of doing pagination.

Keep in mind that your `requests.get()` and `soup` need to be inside `while` loop as this is what let data be updated.

To exit from the infinite `while` loop we need to check every time if the next page button is active (in the case of eBay, on different websites it might be different) with a `.pagination__next` CSS selector. If it becomes inactive (no next page), we'll `break` out of the loop:

```py
if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
     params['_pgn'] += 1
else:
     break
```

A prettier and more readable way could be to use [parameters `dict`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), it is a convenient way of updating URL search parameters:

```py
params = {
    '_nkw': 'iphone',     # search query  
    '_pgn': 1,            # page number
    '_ipg': 200           # number of products per page
}
```

With frequent requests, the site may start blocking your requests if using `requests` as default `user-agent in requests` library is a [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814). You can learn more about ways to bypass the blocking in the [Reducing the chance of being blocked while web scraping](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/) blog post.

See how pagination works in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-ebay-with-bs4-using-pagination#main.py)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}
    
params = {
    '_nkw': 'iphone',     # search query  
    '_pgn': 1,            # page number
    '_ipg': 200           # number of products per page
}

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html', params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    
    print(f"Extracting page: {params['_pgn']}")

    print("-" * 10)
    
    for products in soup.select(".s-item__info"):        
        try:
            price = products.select_one(".s-item__price").text
        except: 
            price = None        
        try:
            link = products.select_one(".s-item__link")["href"]
        except: 
            link = None
        try:
            title = products.select_one(".s-item__title span").text
        except: 
            title = None
        
        data.append({
          "title" : title,
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })

    if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
        break

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
    "title": "Apple iPhone 7 (Excellent Condition) Factory Unlocked, Verizon, AT&T, T-Mobile",
    "price": "$129.99",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/324760206655?epid=28032604856&hash=item4b9d377d3f:g:3QIAAOSwDRZfsXS~&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4OnuvF3hbbEHp5ShpGLkGWwWNQPFcMOczn8qAbaiRH3JN3RnA%2Fo5KU5rTG1pfDtAJEljpPhRFMqTtzr%2BSxYdqDMdOc%2BOn8hBqRl6b1weyByx9gaI%2FACq1tPY4Y%2B5JQsDZrhGEBmrB7sb4PTTl526RmlKGlU46o6xnn%2Fhkddngh2EKWS4FsFKLjy9fYRaXWCWtmx1wy%2BWtf6%2BngisW38qIbcLjmK28PD2SMrXHw7H58EzkT64JwHduKSxlKKSWktiy0PRGeTBZ5AW2zNoqpXookQ%2FtL2bbmuzMU8SN0nYVzln%7Ctkp%3ABFBM6u6V0Ith"
  },
  {
    "title": "Apple iPhone 11 Pro - 64GB - Space Gray - Factory Unlocked - NO FACE ID",
    "price": "$300.00",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/275240933691?epid=6034218747&hash=item4015a3593b:g:v0oAAOSwcPNg8MAr&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4C%2FemhH0GiJs2YQM%2BWmSUZc7UiKZbdMXYJ9chsRMvB1m1Nz0AdYQIxSs4ocR22nY9ZUElw4hQGn0y261ccNRG2uGjuuZbLznB96IjBsdxtWR3zI%2F9HuxbG5Hsq819Ym9EXqO1ZzAzrEter3VT6aJknjDpLc8pQZq%2B1%2Fwd07gt9fU%2BlNEjAD0fwCoColJ8x89lsxujaVkHEw1rliqHDXALqdaT72Jt16asg6n4aU5pARcFW8SBrtPHXUUd7u4V35DlEphzS4NFr70AffXe8AGjgUv6MU5SSDxm%2F359MGE1JSM%7Ctkp%3ABFBM6u6V0Ith"
  }
  #...
]
```

---

As another option you can use [Ebay Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/ebay-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend.

Example code with pagination:

```py
from serpapi import EbaySearch
from urllib.parse import (parse_qsl, urlsplit)
import os, json

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # serpapi api key    
    "engine": "ebay",                 # search engine
    "ebay_domain": "ebay.com",        # ebay domain
    "_nkw": "iphone",                 # search query
  # "LH_Sold": "1"                    # shows sold items
}

search = EbaySearch(params)        # where data extraction happens

page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dict

    if "error" in results:
        print(results["error"])
        break
    
    for organic_result in results.get("organic_results", []):
        link = organic_result.get("link")
        price = organic_result.get("price")

        data.append({
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })
                    
    page_num += 1
    print(page_num)
    
    if "next" in results.get("pagination", {}):
        params['_pgn'] += 1

    else:
        break

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$123.24",
      "extracted": 123.24
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/174901208061?epid=15051465978&hash=item28b8eca3fd:g:9qkAAOSwM5JhH1-5&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA0EYv8HDEOrSLxH0eIwB1UB5foXEAG8GR4ajz2llsgzSIbbwLB0L6LxZ5%2BkKYXD46p4T%2FALftbn0g3JdvFtTMvnUzaP4QU0rBZdL%2Btge%2Bu8k%2BXIOmRjUCc4OsYb%2BQ9H8Tpxo8sAyxE2HeJ4PFbDJb1m%2FPAoaPZXYEliH22fuHBEsW3ThKHFL4HQDncIZc8Jo7OIiN4esC6anSU3bE330cHPXMF9%2FfBkPeh46%2BOPc97xhsknSQEav0ulOvoEFiKPWLBf1N9LrobncdyaW9USRVZxA%3D%7Ctkp%3ABFBMjJ-p0Ith"
  },
  {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$293.24",
      "extracted": 293.24
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/194316866035?epid=8023709558&hash=item2d3e3011f3:g:DfAAAOSw1ephFOPR&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4NSJ9hyAPoE3EL%2F86975ibO6oGJ9BL4HI5AkaO1CpnUgkAlpF8cadAuGjNZXbb7NorsDrNpRkpSPHhOe9Z0qN9EWi%2B3l1UF%2Fhvs4IX9GPHjoAnyVJJxNH9z7H05O58Zszl6CnNGiI7nMNf9Wbsu9ZYkd4wzDHnpsokoFSm720TeOWpdQrOGWusd7UbAxaXhyoJyw2Ea0%2BJIbs6bgo7UuMy%2F62Na%2F4Nqgtrt5kROM3pYzxw%2FIc%2Fw%2BnbdYKFfO09EstxjjYMVWKx9M7nlMLvGxjH4H85p4eXZ7FyOlEuArUrAW%7Ctkp%3ABFBMjJ-p0Ith"
  }
  # ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append new urls to a list as you find them, and continually iterate through the list of urls extracting the content you are looking for.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as Req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as souce

start_url='https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_fosrp=1&_from=R40&_nkw=iphone&_in_kw=1&_ex_kw=&_sacat=0&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=600&_udhi=4.800&LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=4&_ftrt=901&_ftrv=1&_sabdlo=&_sabdhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=10&_fpos=&LH_SubLocation=1&_sargn=-1%26saslc%3D0&_fsradio2=%26LH_LocatedIn%3D1&_salic=77&_saact=77&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_sop=2&_dmd=1&_ipg=200'

page_urls =[start_url]

for purl in page_urls:

    Client=Req(purl)
    page_html=Client.read()
    Client.close()


    page_soup=souce(page_html, "html.parser")


    containers_listings = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"sresult lvresult clearfix li"})
    container_next=page_soup.find("td",{"class":"pagn-next"})
    next_url=container_next.a["href"]

    #this is where you would add your new link
    if next_url not in page_urls:
        page_urls.append(next_url)

    filename="scrape_ebay.csv"
    f=open(filename,"w")
    headers="item_title,item_link,item_price\n"
    f.write(headers)

    for container in containers_listings:
        item_title=container.h3.text.strip()
        item_link=container.h3.a["href"].strip()
        item_price=container.span.text.strip()

    f.write(item_title + "," + item_link + "," + item_price.replace(",",".") + "\n")

    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I've noticed that the loop that extracts listings data from each page 
goes for 877 iterations and then crashes and I am left with an error message.
And also I've noticed that for some reason the file with the results gets written to only 33 times, but in the console if I put a print(count) in the for loop that extracts the data from the listings I get it to count up to 877 and then it crashes, but those 877 scrapes are not in the file with the results. Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up. It's likely that the loops take a look at all the contents multiple times, however it only adds values it has not seen before. What's the error message seen after the crash?